# Getting variable outside of query block in Nodejs with sqlLite

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sqlite

I want to store all the rows from table to array(arr), I need to get the stored array outside of the defined query section. Is there a way I can get all the rows outside db.each such that I can manipulate them further.

```
var arr=[];
db.each("SELECT * FROM login", function(err, row) {
    var title=row.title;
    var context=row.context;
    var newItem = {
        'user': user,
        'pwd': pwd
    };
    arr.push(newItem);
});     
console.log(arr); //Outputs []
```

Comment: Typical case for a promise!

Comment: I need to prepare JSON from database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `db.each` is an asynchronous function, you need to use another function as a callback, like:

```
var arr=[];
db.each("SELECT * FROM login", function(err, row) {
    var title=row.title;
    var context=row.context;
    var newItem = {
        'user': user,
        'pwd': pwd
    };
    arr.push(newItem);
}, function(){
  console.log(arr)
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseeachsql-param--callback-complete

Comment: Thanks for this quick reply.